# Grails 2.2.1 - Build Error for plugin dependencies

Tags: grails, plugins

I have been using grails for web app development, previously i used to copy the grails project from one system to another do all the necessary config (setting GRAILS_HOME as environment variable etc.)

But last week I copied my development project and set the grails development environment, so when i tried to build the project i got n number of (as listed below) errors related to plugin dependencies... I have not changed the grails Version(2.2.1)
just changed the machine windows 7 to 8. Rest of the dependencies are same.

`
               | Loading Grails 2.2.1 
               | Configuring classpath 
               :: problems summary :: 
               :::: WARNINGS 
                module not found: org.grails.plugins#export;1.5

```
    ==== grailsPlugins: tried 

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#export;1.5!export.jar: 

      D:\Amit_Workspace\My_Workspace\Netbeans_Workspace\TVS/lib/export-1.5.jar 

    ==== grailsHome: tried 

      D:\Amit_Workspace\My_Dev\grails-2.2.1/lib/org.grails.plugins/export/ivy-1.5.xml 

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#export;1.5!export.jar: 

      D:\Amit_Workspace\My_Dev\grails-2.2.1/lib/org.grails.plugins/export/jars/export-1.5.jar 

      D:\Amit_Workspace\My_Dev\grails-2.2.1/lib/org.grails.plugins/export/bundles/export-1.5.jar 

    ==== grailsHome: tried 

      D:\Amit_Workspace\My_Dev\grails-2.2.1\src\libs/export-1.5.xml 

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#export;1.5!export.jar: 

      D:\Amit_Workspace\My_Dev\grails-2.2.1\src\libs/export-1.5.jar 

    ==== grailsHome: tried 

      D:\Amit_Workspace\My_Dev\grails-2.2.1\dist/export-1.5.xml 

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#export;1.5!export.jar: 

      D:\Amit_Workspace\My_Dev\grails-2.2.1\dist/export-1.5.jar 

    ==== grailsHome: tried 

      C:\Users\amit\.grails\2.2.1\cached-installed-plugins/export-1.5.xml 

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#export;1.5!export.jar: 

      C:\Users\amit\.grails\2.2.1\cached-installed-plugins/export-1.5.jar 

    ==== grailsHome: tried 

      D:\Amit_Workspace\My_Dev\grails-2.2.1/plugins/export-1.5.pom 

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#export;1.5!export.jar: 

      D:\Amit_Workspace\My_Dev\grails-2.2.1/plugins/export-1.5.jar 

      |  Error Failed to resolve dependencies (Set log level to 'warn' in             BuildConfig.groovy for more information): 

      - org.grails.plugins:export:1.5 
      - org.grails.plugins:excel-export:0.1.4 
      - org.grails.plugins:ofchart:0.6.3 
      - org.grails.plugins:google-chart:0.5.2 
      - org.grails.plugins:jasper-response:1.0.1 
      - org.grails.plugins:quartz:1.0-RC13 
      - org.grails.plugins:dynamic-jasper:0.6 
      - org.grails.plugins:jasper:1.6.1 
      - org.grails.plugins:modalbox:0.4 
      - org.grails.plugins:filterpane:2.3.2 `
```

I am using windows 8 (64bit), Netbeans 8, grails 2.2.1. Please help me with this. I did lot of google, searched all grails forums didn't find any possible solutions..

Regards, 
  Amit

Comment: Hi Amit, could you please paste your BuildConfig (only part with plugins and dependencies) ?

Comment: `plugins {
        runtime ":hibernate:$grailsVersion"
        runtime ":jquery:1.8.3"
//        runtime ":resources:1.1.6"
//         runtime ":resources:1.2.RC2"
         runtime ':resources:1.2.2'
         


        // Uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable additional resources capabilities
        //runtime ":zipped-resources:1.0"
        //runtime ":cached-resources:1.0"
        //runtime ":yui-minify-resources:0.1.5"

        build ":tomcat:$grailsVersion"

        runtime ":database-migration:1.3.2"

        compile ':cache:1.0.1'
        compile :'webxml:1.4.1'
        
    }`

Comment: dependencies {
        // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes e.g.
         runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.0.8'
         
        runtime 'net.sourceforge.barbecue:barbecue:1.5-beta1'
        runtime 'net.sf.barcode4j:barcode4j:2.0'
    }

Comment: @ArrrghGrails - I searched alot for this..... I m facing this problem only in Windows8 machine, when i build/clean in my old windows 7 machine everything seems to work fine..even if i create simple test grails project & install any plugin I will get the above mentioned error " WARNINGS module not found: org.grails.plugins#".......Really frustrated with this...dont know why its not working.....:(

Comment: Hello all, It's crazy i havent changed anything but suddenly the very problem (build error) got resolved out of the blue....when i did build all mentioned plugins got downloaded and installed correctly.,....really dont know if i got "convention over configuration" but definitely got anger & frustration for this issue..